# Groovy : Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

New to Groovy.  Using scripts as part of Jenkins pipeline.  Editing in Sublime with only a linter.

Receiving this error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>
> file:/var/jenkins_home/jobs/{repo}/branches/master/builds/9/libs/{jenkins-library-name}/src/{srcPath}/Pom_EX.groovy: 12:
>
> Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor. 
>   at line: 12 column: 11.

[image: Capture of offending code]

Comment: Class name and constructor function name are case sensitive - you called your class `Pom_EX` and you defined constructor `Pom_Ex`

Answer (score 1):

Really beat myself up here for taking so long to see it.  I didn't see it, since I've been working in Java for a few years now - and the IDE points out this type of mistake.  Name of the constructor didn't match the class....

I reproduced the problem with a dummy class.

[image: Reproduce the problem]

Running `DUMMY d = new DUMMY('blah')` produced :

> 1 compilation error:
>
> Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor. at line: 5 column: 11. File: file:/{path}/DUMMY.groovy at line: 5, column: 11